# Drone which lifts an iPhone in the air

Tags: smartphones, drone

Part of a project I want to scan the GSM signal on a specific surface with an iPhone (specifically iPhone SE). I consider that a drone could do that.

What would be the best drone for this operation: to lift an iPhone SE as high as possible (about 30 meters would be fine)?

Is there any drone which is lighter than 500 grams and would be able to do what I want (I'd prefer <0.5Kg, because the legal stuff would be simpler)?

Is there any better device than a drone to scan the GSM signal in different points of my garden (different heights too)?